# Using Lists that give permissions

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write this code for my project but it doesn't seem to work.

As you can see from the code, the last `else` statement won't work. I have a class `Admin` and it has 3 properties, `Username`, `Password`, and `Permitted`. I created a `List` with default values and granted some usernames permission while granting some no permission. From the `else` statement, I'm trying to match if the `Permitted` value is `true` then that user has permission, and vice versa, however even if the user has no permission is still grants him access. Any idea why?

```
List<Admin> result = FrmMain.AdminL.FindAll(adm => adm.UserName == txtUsername.Text);
if (result.Count == 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Username is incorrect");
}
// Note to miss : I couldnt find a way to link the password with a specific user
List<Admin> result2 = FrmMain.AdminL.FindAll(adm => adm.PassWord == txtPassword.Text);
if (result2.Count == 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Password is incorrect");
}
else
{
    List<Admin> permission = FrmMain.AdminL.FindAll(adm => adm.Permitted  == true);
    if (result.Count > 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("User has been authenticated");
        FrmAdminCP f1 = new FrmAdminCP();
        f1.ShowDialog();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Im sorry, you do not have permission to access the control panel");
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried walking through the code in the debugger and examining the variable values to determine why? That should be your first step.

Comment: I just deleted my comment saying you are incorrectly matching the password - I just saw your note that you are saying you weren't able to match the password of a specific user. Here's how you'd do it: `FrmMain.AdminL.FindAll(adm => adm.PassWord == txtPassword.Text && adm.UserName == txtUserName.Text);`

Comment: without seeing the rest of your code it's hard to know, but the way you authenticate users is problematic to say the least. You need to check the user name and password together. `adm => adm.UserName == txtUsername.Text && adm.PassWord == txtPassword.Text`.

Comment: On a side note, if you're going to allow users to choose their own passwords, I strongly suggest doing some research on [salted password hashing](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/704865/Salted-Password-Hashing-Doing-it-Right) so that you're not storing the users' passwords in clear text where they can be easily stolen.

Comment: @pep Yeah, I do not know how to match it with specific users, but hopefully my teacher would let that one slide.

Comment: Ah, if it's a school project, you can disregard my suggestion regarding password hashing; that said, it's worth learning about.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Thank you!!! that fixed the username and password matching, now I just have to fix my original issue regarding permissions

Comment: @DanBryant Its always good learning more, thanks for the suggestion, I will look it up

Comment: @user3694341 - regardless of it being a school project, I would consider correctly matching a user's password as a vitally important piece of this component. Because it's just a school project, things like password hashing and security do not matter as much, but that other part is key conceptually. But now you have it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to combine your predicates into a single search using &&.

```
List<Admin> result = FrmMain.AdminL.FindAll(adm => 
    adm.UserName == txtUsername.Text && 
    adm.PassWord == txtPassword.Text && 
    adm.Permitted  == true);
if (result2.Count == 1)
{
  // authenticated with access
}
```

or two steps

```
List<Admin> result = FrmMain.AdminL.FindAll(adm => 
    adm.UserName == txtUsername.Text && 
    adm.PassWord == txtPassword.Text);
if (result.Count == 1)
{
  // authenticated 
}
else
{
  // not authenticated
}


List<Admin> result = FrmMain.AdminL.FindAll(adm => 
    adm.UserName == txtUsername.Text && 
    adm.Permitted  == true);
if (result.Count == 1)
{
  // username is permitted to access
}
```

Update:

I'm assuming FrmMain.AdminL is a `List<Admin>`.

```
Admin singleResult = FrmMain.AdminL.Find(adm => 
    adm.UserName == txtUsername.Text);

if(singleResult == null)
{
    MsgBox("No User found");
    return; // exit the subroutine you're in
}

if(singleResult.PassWord != txtPassword.Text)
{
    MsgBox("Wrong Password");
    return; // exit the subroutine you're in
}

if(singleResult.Permitted == false)
{
    MsgBox("Not authorized")
    return;
}
```

Comment: Amazing, this worked. The only issue is now how can I create a specific message box? One that tells the user whether username or password was wrong or he has no permission

Comment: added example based on your comment.